# Configure routing between two VPN clients through RRAS 2012

Tags: vpn, rras

I need to connect to my office network from home.

I have set up vpn connection on my home laptop and vpn connection on one of my office servers (internal network, IP - 10.0.0.13, connects through router to Internet). Both connections connect to my internet server, that has RRAS role installed (windows 2012).

Both connections work. My home laptop receives 10.0.0.101, while my RRAS has 10.0.0.100 address.

The problem is that I cannot see (ping, tracert) the internal server from my home laptop - somewhere I should define that both connections should connect between them (route traffic?).
I has no experience in configuring VPN.

Another thought - maybe it's firewall problem? I have windows firewall on RRAS server.

Any thoughts?
Thank you!